# Face recognition keras dimentionality problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

We are trying do image recognition with keras but we are getting get following error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_93_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (4999, 40)`.So we read image data with `imread` then we put it on an array but for some reason keras wants a fourth dimension.

this is how we read file:

```
def generator(BatchSize):
text_file = open("/content/list_attr_celeba.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
lines = lines[2:]
prew = 1
e = []
while True:
    for i in range(prew,prew+BatchSize):
        #print(i)
        lines[i] = lines[i].split()
        name = lines[i][0]
        lines[i] =  lines[i][1:]
        a = imread('/content/img_align_celeba/' + name)
        #b =  numpy.zeros(4,1)
        #print(a)
        e.append(numpy.array(a))            
        if i % BatchSize == 0 and i != 0:
            yield (numpy.array(lines[prew:i]),e)                
            e = []
            prew = i+1
```

This is how we define generator and model

```
 gen = generator(5000)
 model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=((170,140,3))))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = 
['accuracy'])
```

This is how we fit

```
model.fit_generator(gen, epochs=2, verbose=1,  max_queue_size=10, 
workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False, shuffle=False, initial_epoch=0, 
steps_per_epoch = 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape your data to be `(4999, 40,1)`, e.g. add a dimension of size 1, `conv2d` expects `(batch_size, x, y, filters)`.

```
a = numpy.array(a)
e.append(a.reshape((a.shape + (1,)))
```